# How can I get ripples with the Waves modifier in 2.8?

Tags: animation, modifiers, subdivision-surface, geometry

As seen [in this tutorial](https://youtu.be/gBWaARrOiyE?t=95), adding a *Waves Modifier* to a subdivided plane results in multiple concentric ripples - and that's the behavior I remember from versions of Blender prior to 2.8.

However, when using 2.8 and adding a *Waves Modifier* to a subdivided plane, I seem to get only a single wave which deforms the plane, even when editing the *Width* and *Narrowness* etc values.

How can I recreate the earlier behavior with the current modifier?

It seems like I can get something close to the behaviour from the video with the following settings - but they're fairly extreme. Am I missing a 'frequency' setting or something?

[image]

I downloaded 2.77, as this is the version used the aforentioned tutorial and the *Waves Modifier* works identically to how it works in 2.8, requiring extreme values to create multiple ripples.

But in the tutorial video, Gleb just brings in a new plane, subdivides until there’s 66,049 verts and adds the modifier:

[image]

Default values, no changes to *Width* or *Narrowness* and yet there are the desired ripples. I’m baffled.

Comment: You need a very low Width value in order to see multiple waves, have you tried that?

Comment: Yep - as demonstrated in my edited question. That's weird, I thought I edited that fairly fast, but folks are responding as if they didn't see my addition. Hmm. Thanks for the comment, @moonboots - Do you think the 'low Width value' is intended behaviour or could it be a bug?

Comment: it looks like it worked the same way in 2.7, I don't know why they set this value this way

Comment: Well, to clarify, then, do you think that the values set in this manner is an 'error'? Or at least worth raising with the dev team?

Comment: it must have its reason, it refers to the unit, but it should be corrected so that by default its much higher, because it doesn't fit with the default size of a plane

Answer (score 2):

The *Wave Modifier* seems to be somewhat broken (or at least very unintuitive).
It works best with larger objects, and doesn't scale very well.

Here is an example of my settings on a 1x1m plane, just to help you out.
I couldn't make it work on a smaller plane.

[image]

And while this image from [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/wave.html) is sweet, the manual's reccomended settings don't seem to work well either.

[image]

Comment: This tracks with my experience. I should mention, I did manage to achieve the effect I was looking for (if you look at the edit to the question above), and had taken note of the sweet image from the Blender Manual. Given this behaviour, do you think this is worth reporting as a bug - or at least as an error?